# c++ grade calculator console error

Tags: c++, console, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

I am getting a segmentation fault in console while running the program
i am using codeblocks in ubuntu(linux)

it compiles with 0 errors and 0 warnings

code in pastebin
http://pastebin.com/wgSHPQjc

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Year
{
    public:

Year(string sone, string stwo, string sthree, string sfour, string sfive, string ssix, string sseven, string seight)  // constructor
{
        subjectName[0] = sone;
        subjectName[1] = stwo;
        subjectName[2] = sthree;
        subjectName[3] = sfour;
        subjectName[4] = sfive;
        subjectName[5] = ssix;
        subjectName[6] = sseven;
        subjectName[7] = seight;

        sum = 0;
        percentage = 0;
}
void nameOfSem(string semName) // semster name
{
    name = semName;
    cout << "Enter your " << name  << " marks"<< endl;
}
//no of subjects in semster and  store marks in an array
void readMarks(int noOfSubjects)
{
    subjects = noOfSubjects;
    for(int i=0; i<subjects; i++)
    {
        cout << subjectName[i]; // print out subject name stored in the array
        cin >> yearName[i]; // input from keyboard of marks
        // while loop so that user enters marks from 0 to 100
        while (yearName[i]<0 || yearName[i] > 100 )
        {
            cout << "incorrect input please enter again: ";
            cin >> yearName[i];
        }
    }
}

// function for calculating avarage
void avarage()
{
    for(int j=0; j<subjects; j++) // addtion of marks (addtion of array)
    {
        sum += yearName[j];
    }
    cout << "the total  is : " << sum << endl;
    percentage = float(sum) / float(subjects);
    cout << "The percentage is :  " << percentage << endl;
}

            int sum; // for storing sum of marks

            string name; //  for storing name of the semister
            int subjects; // for storing number of subjects in semister
            float percentage; // calculating percentage in the sem
             int yearName[]; // array for string marks
             string subjectName[]; // array for storin g subject names

};


// main function
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to xxx uni " << endl;

  // constructor for storing subjects name in the array
   Year first("Appiled Physics ", "Electronic Devices circuits ", "Basic electrical Engineering ", "C & Data Structures", "English ", "Mathematical Methods ", "mathematics 1 ", "Engineering Drawing ");

  // name of the sem
   first.nameOfSem("First Year");

   //no of subjects and storing marks in the array
   first.readMarks(8);

   //calculating avarage
   first.avarage();




/*
   Year two( " " , " ", " ")
   second year object

   */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger? (E.g. gdb) What line does it SEGFAULT on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int yearName[]; // array for string marks
string subjectName[]; // array for storin g subject names
```

These two lines should NOT compile if your compiler is Standard conformant.

Use `std::vector` :

```
std::vector<int> yearName;
std::vector<string> subjectName;
```

And then use `push_back` function to add elements to them.

```
Year(string sone, string stwo, string sthree, /*...*/)  
{
        subjectName.push_back(sone);
        subjectName.push_back(stwo);
        subjectName.push_back(sthree);
        //so on    
}
```